# to create a git version number on server during push

Tags: git, tags

I want git to create a version number while files are pushed to the server. I found from search that you can use a pre-recieve hook configuration. Can someone provide a pre-recieve hook?

Should this hook be local and also in server?

Comment: *pre-receive* hooks are strictly remote repository based. You can write hooks in a variety of languages, such as ruby, python or bash (and more). Just pick the language you are most comfortable with and search for examples, you will find various with google.

Answer (score 0):

It should be in server. And I suggest you to use `update` hook in your case.

> The update script is very similar to the pre-receive script, except
>   that it’s run once for each branch the pusher is trying to update. If
>   the pusher is trying to push to multiple branches, pre-receive runs
>   only once, whereas update runs once per branch they’re pushing to.

You can start from the sample in your git repo `hooks/update.sample` just by copying and renaming it to `update`. Git will run it automatically.

You can use `git diff` to get the files changed in your pushed commits, and create `version numbers` for each files though I'm not sure what your `version numbers` here mean.

```
git diff oldrev newrev --name-status -M
```

And I happen to write an `update` hook to prevent any pushes except for a branch called `arc` from any users except for a user called `git-cc-robot`. You may find codes here https://github.com/landys/git-cc-robot/blob/master/scripts/githook/%20update-prevent_master.sh.